# PTVS in VS2013: Why does this for loop not catch the StopIteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I'm using PTVS with Python 3.4.1 in VS2013.

The following code tries to read past the end of the file and throws a StopIteration exception in VS2013. It runs fine in the Python interpreter.

source.csv is a simple csv file saved as a csv from Excel 2013.

csvreader.py:

```
import csv

with open(r"c:\data\source.csv", "r") as reader:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(f=reader, dialect = 'excel')
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
```

source.csv:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
a1,a2,a3
b1,b2,b3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StopIteration` is raised there regardless, it's just that VS actually shows you the point at which it is raised. It doesn't mean that exception is unhandled - if you continue running from that point, you'll see that it works exactly the same.

Now, it shouldn't report this exception by default (the default setting for it in Debug -> Exceptions is report unhandled, so it should only be reported if it's actually unhandled). If you're using PTVS 2.0, then most likely you're hitting [this bug](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2005). I would recommend switching to [2.1 beta](https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/117515), which fixes this among many other things.

Comment: Installing 2.1 fixed it. Thank you.